# Linq to SQL - Order by issue

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Another assignment block!

Basically the problem is that I can't get my output to order the price in a descending order while keeping it grouped by Country.

I know it's probably something so simple but I just can't seem to get it.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Here is the question:
"6. Allow the user view the top five selling products in descending order grouped by country.
(10 marks)"

Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q6 = (from t in northwind.Products
                 orderby t.UnitPrice descending
                 join o in northwind.Suppliers on t.SupplierID equals o.SupplierID
                 group t.UnitPrice by new {o.Country, t.UnitPrice} into grouped
                 select new
                 {
                     Output = grouped.Key

                 }).Take(5);                

        lbxTop5.ItemsSource = q6;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "6. Allow the user view the top five selling products in descending order grouped by country. (10 marks)"

I could read that two ways.

A) Get the top five selling products, group those 5 products by country.
OR
B) For each country, what are the top five selling products?

I think B makes more sense, so I'll do that one.

Also - what is a top selling product?  and how is the country related to it?  I think that the Customer's country matters more than the Supplier's.  Also - I think that Quantity in the OrderDetails can tell me which products are top selling.  Note: your instructor may have other ideas than I do, so use these assumptions at your own peril.

```
from c in northwind.Customers
from o in c.Orders  //all froms except first are calls to SelectMany (one to many)
from od in o.OrderDetails //navigational properties -> no need to write explicit joins
let p = od.Product  // now we go many to one, so we don't need SelectMany
group od
  by new {c.Country, Product = p }   //anon grouping key
  into productGroup
let country = productGroup.Key.Country
let product = productGroup.Key.Product
let quantity = productGroup.Sum(od2 => od2.Quantity)
group new {Product = product, Quantity = quantity} //anon group elements
  by country
  into countryGroup
select new {
  Country = countryGroup.Key,
  Summaries = countryGroup
    .OrderByDescending(summary => summary.Quantity)
    .ThenBy(summary => summary.Product.ProductId) //tiebreaker
    .Take(5)
    .ToList()
}
```

Comment: The output in this ends up as "System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

That's for the summaries!