# Linq to SQL - Output type? (Not displaying information just displaying type)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So guys... I have this question:

> [Allow the user view the top five selling products in descending order grouped by country.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120251/linq-to-sql-order-by-issue)

Here is the code I have:

```
var q6 = (from t in northwind.Products
             join o in northwind.Suppliers on t.SupplierID equals o.SupplierID
             group t.UnitPrice by new {o.Country, t.UnitPrice} into grouped
             let county = grouped.Key.Country
             let price = grouped.Key.UnitPrice
             group new 
             {
                 Country = county,
                 Product = price
             }
             by county
             into countryGrouped
             select new
             {
                 Output = countryGrouped.Key,
                 Price = countryGrouped.OrderBy(c => c.Product)
             });                

        lbxTop5.ItemsSource = q6;
```

It works as far as outputting the prices.

The prices come out like this:

[image: Image of output type]

Can anyone tell me how to output the price in the proper format rather than the datatype?

Thanks!

Comment: This might have to do with you specifying the DISPALY field and the VALUE field on the control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the "propper format"?

You can do something like this:

```
...
select new
{
    Output = countryGrouped.Key,
    Price = string.Join(",", countryGrouped.OrderBy(c => c.Product))
});
```

Which will make the output a comma-delimited string

Comment: Decimal would be fine but as long as it's displaying it doesn't really make a difference!

This code helps! And thank you very much. The only thing is that it's repeating some data, but I'll work around that! Thank you!